# Azure Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand - Run command extension execution is in progress

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying run an simple script on Azure VM (Windows) via `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand` and also via `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet.
Just trying to get the status of DHCP service.

1. Tried after restarting the VMs
2. Created a New VM to run the same script but same error
3. Tried running the invoke command from a different machine

Script stored in a test.ps1 file

```
Get-Service DHCP
```

Command:

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $Resource_Group -VMName $Resource_Name -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath 'C:\Vincent\Azure\AzureVM\Test.ps1'
```

I even tried using Azure API but same error:
Command:

```
$Body = @"
{
  "commandId": "RunPowerShellScript",
  "script": [
    "Get-Service DHCP"
  ]
}
"@

$AppID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$Key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$TenantId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$SubscriptionID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

$GetToken = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token?tenant_id=$TenantId"
$Access_Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $GetToken -Body "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppID&client_secret=$Key&resource=$resource"
$Token = $Access_Token.access_token


$API = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/$Resource_Group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/$VMName/runCommand?api-version=2017-03-30"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $API -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $Token"} -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/json' -OutVariable Result
```

Error:
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand:

> Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand : The Resource
>   'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXXXXX' under resource
>   group 'XXXXXX' was not found. ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound
>   ErrorMessage: The Resource
>   'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXXXXX' under resource group
>   'XXXXXX' was not found. StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: Not Found
>   OperationID : d5a9e664-92e2-45d6-b5e8-b3d5bd65814c At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $Resource_Group -VMName ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand], ComputeCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.InvokeAzureRmVMRunCommand

Error API:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {   "error": {
>       "code": "Conflict",
>       "message": "Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command."   } } At line:23
>   char:1
>   + Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $API -Headers @{Authorization = " ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: According to the error, it may caused by the value of `$Resource_Name`. This value should be the `Name of a VM`,such as `MyVM`, not a `resourceID`

Comment: I am passing name of the vm not id. $Resource_Name = 'Server201201'

Comment: Sorry for that. Have you checked if this VM has been in that resource group?

Comment: Yes. it is the same resource group. The same code was working yesterday.

Comment: Um... That's weird. Did you do anything to change the VM? If you have any process on it, please update here.

Comment: No did not change anything in the VM. Did not install anything on VM. Just created a new VM with default setting, no extension or software installed. Getting the same error on all VMs

Answer (score 0):

**[Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.0.0)** Run command on the VM.

You will receive the error message when you have given wrong “**ResourceGroupName**”.

You may check the screenshot below: I have provided wrong resource group and changed to correct resource group gives the successful.

[image]

In case, if it shows Run command extension execution is in progress, you can check the operation from **Azure Portal => Activity log:**

[image]

Comment: please read the error i posted...I am not getting resource group not found or resource not found in xxxxx resource group error

Comment: Could you check whether the resource VM is present in the resource group?

Comment: Yes i have checked...If the vm resource was not present in the resource group, the error would be 'The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxxxx' under resource group 'xxxxxxx' was not found'

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a "resource not found" error:

> Error: Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand:
>
> Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand : The **Resource**
>   'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXXXXX' under resource group
>   'XXXXXX' **was not found**. ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound ErrorMessage: The
>   Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXXXXX' under resource
>   group 'XXXXXX' was not found. StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: Not Found
>   OperationID : d5a9e664-92e2-45d6-b5e8-b3d5bd65814c At line:1 char:1 +
>   Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $Resource_Group -VMName
>   ... +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand], ComputeCloudException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.InvokeAzureRmVMRunCommand
> ```

And then you're getting an error saying "You're running invoke-azurermvmruncommand", wait till that's completed:

> Error API:
>
> Invoke-RestMethod : { "error": { "code": "**Conflict**", "message": "**Run
>   command extension execution is in progress**. Please wait for completion
>   before invoking a run command." } } At line:23 char:1 +
>   Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $API -Headers @{Authorization = "
>   ... +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
> WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
> ```

run this to check if the VM is where it's supposed to be, and then your script:

```
get-azurermvm -resourcegroupname $Resource_Group -Name $Resource_Name
$file = "C:\Vincent\Azure\AzureVM\Test.ps1"
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $Resource_Group -VMName $Resource_Name -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath $file
```

If that still doesn't work, please share with us `$Resource_Name.GetType()` and `$Resource_Group.GetType()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Set-AzureRmContext` before calling `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand`, by setting the `-SubscriptionName` from the Virtual Machine's Subscription.